# Animated page transistions with jquery [Revisited]

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide

Okay so I've been looking at the other posts about page transistions. But I haven't found anything specifically for what I need. So I got 3 menu items. About, Services & Contact.

[image]

I need to have 3 content divs (can have a class="content") which will initially be hidden. clicking any of the menu items will animate the content div and center it vertically and horizontally into view on the page.

[image]

If there is any div visible at present. clicking any menu item will hide that one and animate the new one in.

Note that jquery also needs to check the visible content's height (as each div may contain more or fewer text) and center the div horizontally and vertically, much like what modal lightboxes are done I guess. I hope the visual guides describe what I need. How do I do this with jquery? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [the `.animate()` API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Here's an example:

```
$(div).show().animate({
    "margin-top": "-16em"
}, {
    "duration": 500,
    "easing": "swing",
    "complete": function () {},
    "step": function (now, fx) {},
    "queue": false,
    "specialEasing": {}
});
```

and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93HjV/

Comment: Awesome! I guess with a bit of work around I can pull this off. Sorry, I forgot all about this project question.

Answer (score 1):

Jqtouch maybe a useful tool for your needs. It´s mainly designed for mobile browser but as it works in desktop browser, it could be useful. www.jqtouch.com

Take a look of this example: (slide up) http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#animations

However, to center de content vertically, you may be write a little bit of css code (not sure).

Comment: This would be perfect for another project I will be doing.